# start 2 dockers of the same build with different variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arguments

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# beginning of the the docker ...
ARG SIGNAL_ID
CMD python ./my_repo/my_main.py --signal_id $SIGNAL_ID
```

I also have a `docker-compose.yml` with all the needed information for the service

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_app:
    build: .
# additional info ...
```

How would I run two services with different `SIGNAL_ID`'s based on the same Docker files?

I have tried the following, however I am unsure how to run them as both of them would be named `my_app`:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg SIGNAL_ID=5
docker-compose build --build-arg SIGNAL_ID=6
```

Maybe there is a way to pass `SIGNAL_ID` not via the build-arg but directly to the `Dockerfile` during `docker-compose up`?

 something similar to `docker run -e SIGNAL_ID=5`?

---

You could have two different `docker-compose.yml`'s, but considering that the only difference between them would be `SIGNAL_ID`, I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to make `$SIGNAL_ID` not a build argument, but an environment variable. As far as can be seen here, it is only used at runtime (in the `CMD` command), not during the build.

So what you could do is:

Remove the `ARG` command from your Dockerfile:

```
CMD python ./my_repo/my_main.py --signal_id $SIGNAL_ID
```

In your `docker-compose` file, create two services with different environment variables:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_app1:
    environment:
    - SIGNAL_ID=1
  my_app2:
    environment:
    - SIGNAL_ID=2
```

And that's it. You can now start using

```
docker-compose up
```

To start without docker-compose, you can simply

```
docker build -t image-name .
docker run -e SIGNAL_ID=1 image-name
docker run -e SIGNAL_ID=2 image-name
```

Comment: Inside the `Dockerfile` is this `ENV SIGNAL_ID $SIGNAL_ID` necessary for env variables ?

Comment: It's useful if you want to set default values in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with environment variable. You have the following options:

Example `docker-compose.yaml` (The `MESSAGE` will be displayed on the webserver)

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    environment:
      MESSAGE: ${MESSAGE}
    image: "bithavoc/hello-world-env"
    ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

---

1. `.env` file

In the directory where your docker-compose.yaml is located, place a file with the env variable:

```
MESSAGE="Message from File"
```

To run it:
`docker-compose up`

Test it:
`curl localhost:3000` should print the text from the `.env` file.

---

2. Export the variable via CLI

To run it:
`MESSAGE="Message from CLI" docker-compose up`

To test it:
`curl localhost:3000` should print the variable which you have in front of your `docker-compose up`

---

Link for more documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file